# Modify an exisiting OSM leaflet map and add POI

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I wanted to know if it's possible to use the map here (not mine) : https://www.vinci-autoroutes.com/fr/autoroutes-temps-reel (it's an official french road traffic service) to display it in my website and modify the zoom, location and add some point of interest ?
Like that screenshot I edit : 
[image: leaft]

And if it's possible I want to know how do it ^^ 
thx

Comment: The answer is [yes](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html). Please consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: Are you sure ? I speak about modify  a map I do not own , on a website I don't own at all. More I am google it, more I think it's not possible to do it ...

Comment: If you take this map could you by code zoom for exemple ? 
https://www.vinci-autoroutes.com/fr/autoroutes-temps-reel

Comment: From a technical point of view this should be possible. However it depends on various conditions, for example if the server allows you to access their data (i.e. the markers) from a third-party server. It also depends on if you are allowed to use their map tiles, from a legal point of view. The answer to this is probably no unless they granted you explicit permissions. tl;dr: Technically: yes/maybe. Legally: maybe/no.